# Django непонятная ошибка

Tags: python, django, python-2.x, python-2.7

Уже довольно долго не могу понять, что за ошибка в работе проекта на Django 1.8 (Python 2.7, uwsgi), и самое главное - куда копать? Ошибка появилась после переноса сайта на новый сервер

```
[django.request:256] Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 89, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 95, in inner
    if_modified_since = request.META.get("HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE")
AttributeError: 'Article' object has no attribute 'META'
```

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, код `models.py` и `views.py`, в которых модель `Article` используется.

Comment: Не думаю, что проблема в коде, так как ошибка появилась после переноса сайта с одного сервера на другой